# Mysql: ORDER BY joined table column

Tags: mysql

```
        SELECT 
            u.*,
            ur.friend_id,
            COUNT(
                IF(um.to_user_id = ?,
                    (IF(um.`date` >= ulr.last_read,um.message_id,NULL))
                ,NULL)
            ) as new_messages
            ,i.t_1 AS user_photo
        FROM user_relationships ur
        LEFT JOIN `user` u ON u.user_id=ur.friend_id
        LEFT JOIN user_messages um ON um.from_user_id=ur.friend_id
        LEFT JOIN user_last_read ulr ON ulr.read_who=ur.friend_id

        LEFT JOIN ads a ON a.user_id=u.user_id
        LEFT JOIN images i ON a.id=i.ad_id

        WHERE ur.user_id=?
        GROUP BY ur.friend_id
        ORDER BY new_messages DESC
```

I need this part `i.t_1 AS user_photo` to be in DESC order, because there can be multiple user_photos and i need to pick the newest one.

I have used old solution with `GROUP_CONCAT(i.t_1 ORDER BY i.image_id DESC) AS user_photo`.
But i need only one image, instead of all available. :)

Thanks ;)

Comment: Where exactly is your question?  Is this query not working?  Do you need this query modified to do something else?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: I need i.t_1 AS user_photo to be in DESC order while keeping ORDER BY new_messages DESC untouched.

Comment: Which do you want to order by first?  It sounds like you either want `ORDER BY new_messages DESC, i.t_1 DESC` or `ORDER BY i.t_1 DESC, new_messages DESC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    u.*,
    ur.friend_id,
    COUNT(
        IF(um.to_user_id = ?,
            (IF(um.`date` >= ulr.last_read,um.message_id,NULL))
        ,NULL)
    ) as new_messages,
    (
        SELECT t_1 
        FROM images 
        WHERE ad_id = a.id 
        ORDER BY t_1 DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS user_photo
FROM 
    user_relationships ur
    LEFT JOIN `user` u ON u.user_id=ur.friend_id
    LEFT JOIN user_messages um ON um.from_user_id=ur.friend_id
    LEFT JOIN user_last_read ulr ON ulr.read_who=ur.friend_id
    LEFT JOIN ads a ON a.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE ur.user_id=?
GROUP BY ur.friend_id
ORDER BY new_messages DESC
```

Comment: Yeah i have tried it. Too much logic in subquery :). I have to put all joins there as well, because subquery should pick images only of friends etc.

Comment: @Beck I don't understand. Can you explain more? Doesn't this query give you the needed result?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be 100% sure without looking at the table create statements, but something like this should work:

```
GROUP BY ur.friend_id, i.ad_id ORDER BY new_messages DESC, i.t_1 DESC
```

By the way, I think you're being too harsh with your database. Pull some logic from queries to application, scripting languages usually can do better then database engine.

Comment: Nope, returns dublicated rows.